# How to compare date in template?

Tags: django, django-templates

I have model with datetime field:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
```

And I want to compare year from this dates with number:

```
{% for object in my_objects %}
    {% if object.create_date.year > "2011" %}
        ...
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the year property of datetime object should be returning an integer not a string

`{% if object.create_date.year > 2011 %}`